# When we use D3.js to draw histograms (bar charts), can we use scaleOrdinal()?

Tags: d3.js

I used `scaleBand()` to draw histograms, but since `scaleOrdinal()` is also for discrete values, so I tried to change `scaleBand()` to `scaleOrdinal()` to draw the bar chart.

But do we normally use `setOrdinal()` to draw bar charts? It seems we could, but we have to manually calculate the `bandwidth()` and `x` of each item?  If it is `scaleBand()`, it is all calculated for us:

```js
const scaleX = d3.scaleBand().domain(["A", "B", "C"]).range([0, 1000]);
console.log(scaleX("A"), scaleX("B"), scaleX("C"), scaleX.bandwidth());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.6.2/d3.js" integrity="sha512-6G9G63qZLxEcLqVyklArI/2ZgWK1HdKMU9yWbQUJC/eSsLsaY0NZKv4JDW4ltw1Z9sEvFB3DP54GzOIkIJjyLg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The [documentation said it is the most often used scale function](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaleordinal), but it seems it merely does some kind of 1 to 1 mapping, so can't we just use JavaScript's object or `Map() object` to do the same?  I don't quite see why it is the most often used scale function if it is just one to one mapping: then what visualization do we use it for?

Comment: It depends on what you need to draw. ordinal() is a scale for points, while band() is for objects with width like bars

Comment: you mean for scatterplot or line chart, we'd use `scaleOrdinal()`? but I thought we'd use `scaleLinear()` for those?

Comment: You actually can draw a chart without scales by calculating coordinates manually. In any case, both band and ordinal are kinds of linear scale with nuances (unlike, for example, logarithmic scale), so it does not matter a lot - just use what's working for you